# What is a simple way to only grab dependancies from a Maven Artifactory Repository and run a Maven build in Jenkins Declarative Pipeline Syntax?

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

For my pipeline's build step I am just looking to authenticate to Artifactory and run a simple `mvn clean install`, however I am getting "Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized" errors relating to Artifactory.  I am running my Maven build from within an isolated build container that I spin up via Kubernetes.  I have checked out the [JFrog documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins) but am so far unsuccessful with setting things up in my Jenkinsfile.  Essentially I want to be able to only grab the dependencies from my Maven Artifactory Repo and run my build. Here is what I'm currently trying but the build seems to skip right through everything once it hits the build step:

```
pipeline {
agent {
    kubernetes {
      cloud 'cloud-test'
      label 'label-test'
}

options {
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '10'))
}

environment{
    def ART_CREDENTIALS = credentials('artifactory-connect')
    def ART_USR = "${env.ART_CREDENTIALS_USR}"
    def ART_PSW = "${env.ART_CREDENTIALS_PSW}"
}

stages {
    stage('Run in Build Container') {
        steps {
            container('build-container') {
                script{
                    sh 'echo Running Maven Build...'
                    // Look at how to authorize to Arty here
                    def server = Artifactory.server 'arty-server'
                    rtMaven.resolver server: server, releaseRepo: 'sysdse-maven-local', snapshotRepo: 'snapshots'
                }
                sh 'mvn clean install'
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Run Application') {
        steps {
            container('App-Container') {
                //Run App
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Run Tests'){
        steps {
            container('App-Container'){
                //Run Tests
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is Jenkins Artifactory Plugin installed - https://github.com/JFrog/jenkins-artifactory-plugin ? Is Artifactory server setup in Jenkins configuration (Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System) ? Also, you are missing `def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()` declaration in your pipeline script above the rtMaven.resolver line.

Comment: Yeah Artifactory Plugin 2.16.2 is installed, also the Artifactory server is configured in the Configure System page and connecting successfully as I've used it elsewhere.  This summarized snippet of my Jenkinsfile is my most recent attempt, I did have the `def rtMaven = Artifactory newMavenBuild()` declaration in there previously but I received the same results.  If possible I'd like to not do an "Artifactory Build" but just make sure my container is able to download all needed dependencies, and then run its own Maven build.

Comment: The credentials configured for Artifactory server, does it have access to the repo you are downloading dependencies from ?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish what I was looking for by adding the following to my /path/to/.m2/conf/settings.xml in my docker build container and then committing that:

```
<server>
  <id>artifactory-repo-id</id>
  <url>https://artifactory.location/</url>
  <username>user@email.com</username>
  <password>secret-http-token</password>
</server>
```

So my resulting build stage in my Jenkinsfile looks like:

```
stage('Run in Build Container') {
    steps {
        container('build-container') {
            script{
            sh 'echo Running Maven Build...'
            sh 'mvn clean install'
        }
    }
}
```